# Packing the minimum number of circles between a cone defined by two circles

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-geometry

[image]

I have a problem involving spheres that can be simplified to that of two circles $A$ and $B$ with radii $a$ and $b$.  You can imagine a cone (dashed lines) being defined between the extremities of the two circles along the line that passes through their centres.

I want to find and construct the minimum number of other circles along that line.

The conditions for the new circles are:

1. Their radii interpolate between that of the radii of $A$ and $B$ along the connecting centre line
2. Their extremities touch the sides of the 'cone edges'
3. The centre of the new circles are positioned along the line, on the perimeter of the preceding circle

As the circles interpolate their radii I get:

radius = $a + (b - a)*\frac{i}{n}$

Where $n$ is the count of circles minus one (including $a$ and $b$), and $i$ is the integer index from $0$ to $n$ for the circle (including $a$ and $b$).

As I know the distance d between the centres of $A$ and $B$, if I consider the sum of the radii of the circles along the line that must equal $d$ I get a series:

$[a + (b - a)*\frac{i}{n}]*k^i + ... = d + b$

Where $k$ is the scaling factor that interpolates the radii of the circles between $A$ and $B$.

Now I need to find the minimum integer $n$, and along with that the associated value for $k$ (which is easy from one of the terms when $n$ is found).  I am not sure where to go from here?  I notice that series is almost geometric but each term also involves $i$a in the coefficient.

Comment: None of your conditions requires any interpolating circles. If there none, all three conditions are satisfied vacuously. Even if you insist there should be at least one (assuming $A, B$ are far enough apart for one to fit), Then the minimum number would be $1$, because you've not given any condition that would require more be added. Now if you were to add a fourth condition stating that it must be impossible to add an additional interpolating circle, that would require more. Obviously the trick there would be to place the circles just far enough apart another circle cannot be added.

Comment: If you want to find the minimum that will not allow any more circle to be added, the trick is to instead fill the region with as many circles as possible, leaving any unfillable gap between $B$ and its nearest neighbor. Then starting with $A$'s neighbor, remove every other circle (not including $B$). If there is a gap next to $B$, enlarge it just slightly - not enough to allow another circle - by moving the remaining circles a tiny bit towards their larger neighbor. This will prevent the removed circles from being able to be added back in, but only just barely. So this is the minimum.

Comment: If there is no gap by $B$ in the initial filling, and an odd number of circles overall, no matter how small movements are made to the intermediate circle, the last gap will allow another circle, so you will need an additional circle in that case. You can use the full filling to find the radii of the intermediate circles, but the actual formula is more complicated than yours. The radius is given by $$r_i = a - \frac{b-a}d (a +r_i + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{i-i} r_k)$$ which must be solved to bring both $r_i$ to one side.

Comment: I've realised that I have been super dumb and that of course there is only one circle that can be added that fits the constraints of hitting the 'cone edges' and being placed on the perimeter of the prior circle.  So my question probably should have been if circles were placed like that whether they always fit, or leave a gap?  I suspect they leave a gap most of the time?  What I really want to do is fill the space in between with the minimum number of circles that preserve some metric of 'aesthetic volume' - apologies for that being ill defined.

Comment: So I should fill the space with circles subject to my constraints, which will either fit exactly (unlikely), or result in a series that undershoots leaving a gap, or overshoots.  Because I want a conservative estimate of the volume filled.  Then adjust my scaling if they overshot.  But if they undershoot I would actually have to relax my constraint on them being placed on the perimeter of each prior circle.

Comment: I'm afraid that "aesthetic volume" is not just ill-defined. I have no clue at all what you would mean by it. But yes, to leave no gaps would require that the distance between $A$ and $B$ is exactly one of a certain sequence of discrete values. For any other distances, there will be a gap. If selecting a distance by any continuous probability distribution, the probability of not having a gap would be exactly $0\%$ (but remember, when there are infinitely many possible outcomes, $0$ probability does not mean it will never occur, just that it is incredibly unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

If as per your comments, you just want to fill the space with circles tangent to the borders, and to each other (except when no longer possible), then the calculation would be as such. For convenience, I am going to scale all distances by the radius $a$. Thus, the larger circle will always have radius $1$. For other scales, you will just have to multiply all distances by $a$.

By linearity, if a circle tangent to the two borders is placed with center on the medial line at a distance of $x$ from the center of $A$, then its radius should be given by $$r = 1 - \frac {x}d(1-b) = 1 - tx$$
where $t := \frac{1-b}d$.
If the first circle placed is to be tangent to $A$, then the distance from its center to the center of $A$ is the sum of the two radii. That is, $x = r_1 + 1$. So
$$r_1 = 1 - t(r_1 + 1)\\r_1(1+t) = 1-t\\ r_1 = \frac{1-t}{1+t}$$
It will be convenient to define $q = \frac{1-t}{1+t}$. So $r_1 = q$. Also $1 - q = \frac{2t}{1+t}$.

The second circle will be at a distance of $1+2q + r_2$, so
$$r_2 = 1 - t(1+2q +r_2)\\r_2(1+t) = 1-t-2qt)\\r_2 = \frac{1-t}{1+t}-\frac{2qt}{1+t} = q\frac{1+t - 2t}{1+t} = q^2$$

If we assume that circle $i$ has radius $r_i = q^i$ for all $i< k$, then circle $k$ is at a distance of $$1 + r_k + 2\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} q^i =r_k - 1 + 2\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} q^i = r_k - 1 + 2\frac{1-q^k}{1 - q} = r_k + \frac{1 + q - 2q^k}{1-q}$$

So
$$r_k = 1 - t\left(r_k +  \frac{1 + q - 2q^k}{1-q}\right)\\
r_k(1+t)(1-q) = 1 - q - t - tq + 2tq^k = (1-t) - q(1+t) + 2tq^k\\
r_k(1-q) = \frac{1-t}{1+t} - q + \frac{2}{1+t}2q^k\\r_k(1-q) = q - q+ (1-q)q^k\\r_k = q^k$$

By induction, $r_k = q^k$ for all $k$. When circle $A$ is not scaled to a radius of $1$, this becomes $$q = \frac{d + b -a}{d+a-b}\\r_k = q^ka$$

Now the sum of the diameters of all the intermediary circles must be $\le d - a - b$ in order for the circles to fit. For $k$ intermediary circles,

$$2a\sum_{i=1}^k q^k \le d - a -b\\a2q\frac{1-q^k}{1-q} \le d - a -b$$
$\frac{2q}{1-q} = \frac{d - a + b}{a-b}$, so
$$(1-q^k)a\frac{d - a + b}{a-b} \le d - a - b\\
1 - \frac{(d - a - b)(a-b)}{(d-a + b)a} \le q^k$$
Taking the logarithm of both sides (and noting that since $q < 1, \log q < 0$), we get $$ k \le \dfrac{\log\left(1 - \frac{(d - a - b)(a-b)}{(d-a + b)a}\right)}{\log q}$$
Which gives the upper limit on how many intermediary circles can be added.

The total area of the intermediary circles (not including $A$ or $B$) will be $$\pi\sum_{i=1}^k (q^ia)^2 = \pi a^2q^2\frac{1-q^{2k}}{1-q^2}$$

Note that if you want a minimum on the area of the circles, you should exchange $a$ and $b$ in the above, as shifting the circles towards the smaller end, leaving the gap next to the large end circle, will make their total area go down.

Comment: The volume of all intermediary spheres would be $$\frac {4\pi}3a^3q^3 \frac{1-q^{3k}}{1-q^3}$$